# Why my recaptcha not working on custom domain and working localy?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

Why does my recaptcha only work locally and not in production? I purchased a domain and hosting and copied the entire wordpress website to a new hosting. Recaptcha works great locally, but it won't work like this.

This is my frontend script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=6LcwO98lAAAAABlL7NDEWnIWSPXSiLW9VGkW-2Fb">

    </script>

    <script>
    grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function() {

        grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('6LcwO98lAAAAABlL7NDEWnIWSPXSiLW9VGkW-2Fb', {

            action: 'login'

        }).then(function(token) {

            if (jQuery('.contact-form').length)

                jQuery('.contact-form').prepend(

                    '<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');

            if (jQuery('.newsletter-form').length)

                jQuery('.newsletter-form').prepend(

                    '<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');

            if (jQuery('.subscribe-form').length)

                jQuery('.subscribe-form').prepend(

                    '<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');

        });

    });
    </script>
```

There I put the input with type hidden so that I can use gresponse on the server.

This is mine recaptcha class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Cubestheme_Recaptcha Class
 *
 * @since    2.0.0
 * @package  cubestheme
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'Cubestheme_Recaptcha' ) ) :

class Cubestheme_Recaptcha_Response {
    
    public $success;
    public $errorCodes;
    
}

endif;

if ( ! class_exists( 'Cubestheme_Recaptcha' ) ) :

    $reCaptchaSiteKey = "6LdUDjYlAAAAAJZdeEC6hay0vCqDSezsFAZdogf2";
    $reCaptchaSecret = "6LdUDjYlAAAAAD_1DrUOiyTxZT3tXIk4G14xiNTL";
    

    /**
     * The main Cubestheme_Recaptcha class
     */
    class Cubestheme_Recaptcha {

        /**
         * Params
         */
        private static $_signupUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin";
        private static $_siteVerifyUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?";
        private $_secret;
        private static $_version = "php_1.0";

        /**
         * Setup class.
         *
         * @since 1.0
         */
        public function __construct($secret = "6LdUDjYlAAAAAD_1DrUOiyTxZT3tXIk4G14xiNTL") {
            if ($secret == null || $secret == "") {
                die("To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from <a href='"
                        . self::$_signupUrl . "'>" . self::$_signupUrl . "</a>");
            }
            $this->_secret = $secret;
        }

        /**
        * Encodes the given data into a query string format.
        *
        * @param array $data array of string elements to be encoded.
        *
        * @return string - encoded request.
        */
        private function _encodeQS($data) {
            $req = "";
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $req .= $key . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
            }
            // Cut the last '&'
            $req = substr($req, 0, strlen($req) - 1);
            return $req;
        }

        /**
        * Submits an HTTP GET to a reCAPTCHA server.
        *
        * @param string $path url path to recaptcha server.
        * @param array  $data array of parameters to be sent.
        *
        * @return array response
        */
        private function _submitHTTPGet($path, $data) {
            $req = $this->_encodeQS($data);
            $response = file_get_contents($path . $req);
            return $response;
        }

        /**
        * Calls the reCAPTCHA siteverify API to verify whether the user passes
        * CAPTCHA test.
        *
        * @param string $remoteIp   IP address of end user.
        * @param string $response   response string from recaptcha verification.
        *
        * @return ReCaptchaResponse
        */
        public function verifyResponse($remoteIp, $response) {
            // Discard empty solution submissions
            if ($response == null || strlen($response) == 0) {
                $recaptchaResponse = new Cubestheme_Recaptcha_Response();
                $recaptchaResponse->success = false;
                $recaptchaResponse->errorCodes = 'missing-input';
                return $recaptchaResponse;
            }
            $getResponse = $this->_submitHttpGet(
                    self::$_siteVerifyUrl, array(
                        'secret' => $this->_secret,
                        'remoteip' => $remoteIp,
                        'v' => self::$_version,
                        'response' => $response
                    )
            );
            $answers = json_decode($getResponse, true);
            $recaptchaResponse = new Cubestheme_Recaptcha_Response();
            if (trim($answers ['success']) == true) {
                $recaptchaResponse->success = true;
            } else {
                $recaptchaResponse->success = false;
                $recaptchaResponse->errorCodes = ( isset($answers ['errorCodes'])?$answers['errorCodes']:"error" );
            }
            return $recaptchaResponse;
        }


    }

endif;
```

And this is mine PHP ajax for subscribe:

```
function wordpress_ajax_mailchimp_subcribe() {
    $apikey = "KEY";
    $list_id = "LISTID";

    $email = strval($_POST['email']);
    $gresponse = strval($_POST['gresponse']);
    
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo wp_send_json( array("error" => 1, "message" => __("Invalid email address", "cubestheme") ) );
    }else{
        //ReCaptcha Block
        $response = null;

        // check secret key
        $reCaptcha = new Cubestheme_Recaptcha();

        if ($_POST["gresponse"]) {
            $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["gresponse"]
            );
        }

        print_r($response, true);

        if (is_object($response) && isset($response->success) && $response->success) {
            
            //MailChimp Subscription
            $api = new Cubestheme_MCAPI3($_apikey);
            $name = $email;
            $res = $api->listSubscribe($list_id, $email, $name);


            if(isset($res->title) && $res->title == "Member Exists"){
                echo wp_send_json( array("error" => 1, "message" => __("You are already subscribed to our mailing list", "cubestheme") ) );
                die(); 
            }

            //Send coupon
            $subject = "Thank you for your subscribtion";

            $html = "<h2>Thank you for your subscribtion!</h2>";
            $html .= "<p>You have received a 10% discount voucher for your the next purchase!</p><br>";
            $html .= "<p>You will get the discount by entering the code <b>BOMBAJ2022</b></p><br>";
            $html .= "<p>Visit <a href='https://bombjtextile.com/shop' target='_blank'>BombajTextile Shop</a></p><br><br>";
            $html .= "<p>Best regards, BombajTextile.com</p>";

            function wpse27856_set_content_type(){
                return "text/html";
            }
            add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
    
            wp_mail($email, $subject, $html);
        }else{
            echo wp_send_json( array("error" => 1, "message" => __("Please refresh page to confirm that you are not robot", "cubestheme") ) );
        }
    }


    echo wp_send_json( array("status" => "done", "message" => __("You have successfully subscribed to the mailing list", "cubestheme") ) );

    die();
}
```

And this is my simple ajax in JS:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', 'form.newsletter-form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var email = $(this).find("input[name='newsletter_email']").val();
    var gresponse = $(this).find("input[name='g-recaptcha-response']").val();

    var data = {
      action: 'wordpress_ajax_mailchimp_subcribe',
      email: email,
      gresponse: gresponse,
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function (response) {
        /
      },
      complete: function (response) {
        
      },
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
          jQuery('p.feedback-message').html(response.message);
          return;
        } else {
          jQuery('p.feedback-message').html(response.message);
          
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

I registered my domain on `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin` website and did everything right.